# Converting time_t to int

Tags: c++, epoch

I want to convert a given time into epoch(time_t) and vice versa. can anyone tell what is the routine or algorithm for this?

Thanks

**Update**

```
 epoch_strt.tm_sec = 0;
 epoch_strt.tm_min = 0;
 epoch_strt.tm_hour = 0;
epoch_strt.tm_mday = 1;
epoch_strt.tm_mon = 1;
epoch_strt.tm_year = 70;
 epoch_strt.tm_isdst = -1;

double nsecs = difftime(curtime, basetime);//current time from system, I converrting it to struct tm
```

but this always return 32399 for some reason.

Comment: What format is the "given time" in?

Comment: Yes, we have to know what format you want converted.

Comment: Note that `epoch_strt.tm_mon = 1;` implies February and not January.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should cast it to a `long int` instead of `int`.

```
long int t = static_cast<long int> (time(NULL));
```

An `int` might not be enough to hold the time, for example, on my platform, `time_t` is a `typedef` of `__int64`.

Comment: Why not `intmax_t`? Worth nothing: `time_t` is not guaranteed to be an integer type: it is an arithmetic type, thus possibly floating point. And if the float is too large to fit in `intmax_t`, undefined behavior. POSIX guarantees this won't happen as it says time t returns seconds since EPOCH, so it cannot be that big, but ANSI C leaves it unspecified.

Comment: This is not valid syntax. `static_cast` requires parenthesis around the source value.

Comment: Note that on some (many) platforms, `long int` is exactly the same as `int` (MSVC/Windows, for example). Maybe you were thinking of `long long int`?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you're doing with `time_t`, you'll probably be best off using the `<chrono>` library. Then you can convert to and from `time_t`, if necessary. Hopefully you can just do what you need in `<chrono>`

```
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto a = std::chrono::system_clock::now()
    time_t b = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(a);
    auto c = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(b);
}
```

#### Update:

The C++ standard library doesn't yet have an API for dates as good as `<chrono>` is for time. You can use the Boost date library or you can fall back on the C date library:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::tm epoch_start = {};
    epoch_start.tm_sec = 0;
    epoch_start.tm_min = 0;
    epoch_start.tm_hour = 0;
    epoch_start.tm_mday = 1;
    epoch_start.tm_mon = 0;
    epoch_start.tm_year = 70;
    epoch_start.tm_wday = 4;
    epoch_start.tm_yday = 0;
    epoch_start.tm_isdst = -1;

    std::time_t base = std::mktime(&epoch_start);

    auto diff = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(base);
    std::chrono::seconds s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(diff);

    std::cout << s.count() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: the year should b3 70 or 1970?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm tm_year is years since 1970, so to represent 1970 set tm_year to 1970-1900 = 70

Comment: but i am using standary library. include<time.h> and not chrono.

Comment: @Yogi chrono is part of the standard library, but your implementation might not have it yet since it was just added last year. There's also an implementation in boost. If your standard library doesn't have it and you can't use boost then you can use Rob's solution with `difftime`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `struct tm` to a `time_t`, use `mktime`. To convert a `time_t` to a `struct tm`, use either `gmtime` or `localtime`.

**Sample**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main () {
    std::time_t now = std::time(0);

    std::tm *now_tm = gmtime(&now);

    std::tm tomorrow_tm(*now_tm);

    tomorrow_tm.tm_mday += 1;
    tomorrow_tm.tm_hour = 0;
    tomorrow_tm.tm_min = 0;
    tomorrow_tm.tm_sec = 0;

    std::time_t tomorrow = std::mktime(&tomorrow_tm);

    double delta = std::difftime(tomorrow, now);

    std::cout << "Tomorrow is " << delta << " seconds from now.\n";
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

// Display the difference between now and 1970-01-01 00:00:00
// On my computer, this printed the value 1330421747
int main () {

    std::tm epoch_strt;
    epoch_strt.tm_sec = 0;
    epoch_strt.tm_min = 0;
    epoch_strt.tm_hour = 0;
    epoch_strt.tm_mday = 1;
    epoch_strt.tm_mon = 0;
    epoch_strt.tm_year = 70;
    epoch_strt.tm_isdst = -1;

    std::time_t basetime = std::mktime(&epoch_strt);

    std::time_t curtime = std::time(0);

    long long nsecs = std::difftime(curtime, basetime);

    std::cout << "Seconds since epoch: " << nsecs << "\n";
    assert(nsecs > 42ll * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me for epoch date i.e 1st Jan 1970?.

Comment: Download my 2nd sample program above, and replace the `epoch_strt … = 0` lines with what you need.

Comment: I did that but I dont know why its returning zero. I am using long long for nsec, but when I print nothing appears