# How to correctly cast time_t to long int?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm still learning about type casting in C++ and I'm currently doing this

```
long int t = time(NULL);
```

I'm using VS2013 and noticed the conversion from 'time_t' to 'long' warning so I thought I would type cast it to look like;

```
long int t = static_cast<long int> time(NULL);
```

However this doesn't work yet combining a static cast and a C-style cast works

```
long int t = static_cast<long int> (time(NULL));
```

I was just wondering if anyone could help shed some light on this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That's not "combining a static cast and a C-style cast", it's just the correct syntax for a static cast, which requires `()` around its argument.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed the requirement to put a static cast value in the parenthesis. I've learn't something new.

Comment: Instead of merely restricting the result to the range of `long`, which still (as of 2014) leaves you many years of future dates, you could cast to `unsigned char`, shortening that interval to just 255 seconds into 1970.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483974/converting-time-t-to-int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time(NULL)` is not a cast but a function call which returns `time_t`. Since `time_t` is not exactly the same type as `long int`, you see the warning.

Furthermore, `static_cast<T>(value)` requires the parenthesis, that is why your first version does not work.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. Marking as answer when I can.

Comment: It says I can accept an answer in two minutes. I will do so after those two minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains the answer.  The `static_cast` generic method in the code you provide takes the `time_t` type as its input and converts it to a `long int` as its return value.  This code does not contain a C-style type-cast.

```
long int t = static_cast<long int> (time(NULL));
```

Type-casting should also work too, because [time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) is an arithmetic type and the C cast operator will perform the promotion to the `long int` type.

```
long int t = (long int)time(NULL);
```

This [casting tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) might be an interesting read for you.

Answer (score 0):

A `time_t` value is the number of seconds since the start of Jan 1 1970. Casting that to 32-bit `long` you therefore restrict yourself to values representing time values [before the year 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), roughly. That's not a good idea, and the ungoodness of it is the reason for your warning.

---

The attempted expression

```
static_cast<long int> time(NULL)
```

is just invalid syntax. A `static_cast` requires a parenthesis with the value.

Comment: Is there no big/little endian matter related to this, which needs to use `ntohl` to be compatible everywhere?